# How to find the dimension of a vector space given parametric equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have the vector space $V = \{(a, b, c, d) \in\mathbb{R}^4\; |\; a + c = 0\quad \text{and}\quad b - c + 2d = 0\}$

Then how do I calculate the dimension of the space?

If possible use a similar example as this question is for an assignment.

Please be as detailed as possible in your answer as I have done research on and off stackexchange but I am still blank as to how to approach this.

Comment: A nontrivial linear equation reduces dimension by one.  You have two nontrivial equations, so either they coincide (which they don't) or they reduce the dimension by two.  That gives $4-2=2$ dimensions for the result.

Comment: @vadim123  They can reduce the dimension just  by one without strictly coinciding, for example, e.g. - one being a multiple of the other.

Comment: @uniquesolution, you're right I was vague: if the $n-1$-dimensional subspaces determined by the two equations coincide, then together (their intersection) is $n-1$-dimensional.  Otherwise, the result is $n-2$-dimensional.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this is the case. All material I have found on this course seems to be given without any rationale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix of the coefficients of the linear equations that define $V$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix is row-reduced and has rank $2$. The rank of this matrix is the *codimension* of $V$, i. e. the difference between the dimension of the ambient space (here, $4$) and $\dim V$. In other words, if $V$ is a subspace of the finite dimensional vector space $E$, then:
$$\dim V+\operatorname{codim}V=\dim E. $$
Here you get $\;\dim V+2=4$, whence $\;\dim V=2$.

Answer (score 3):

The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of the minimal generating set which is linearly independent. Now for $V$ we have $a+c=0$ and $b-c+2d=0$. Now from first condition we observe that $c$ is $dependent$ on $a$. And from the second condition we see that $b+2d=c$. Now if we assign any arbitrary value to $a$ then the value for $c$ is fixed and hence the value of $b+2d$ is fixed. Now you can assign any arbitrary value to $b$ and then the value of $d$ is fixed.

Hence $\{a,b\}$ is a $minimal$ generating set which is linearly independent.

Hence $dim\ V=2$.